# Postgres bulk insert/update that's injection-safe. Perhaps a function that takes an array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function, code-injection, bulk

I'm working on paying back some technical debt this week, and it hit me that I have no idea how to make multi-value inserts safe from accidental or malicious SQL injections. We're on Postgres 11.4. I've got a test bed to work from that includes a small table with about 26K rows, here's the declaration for a small table I'm using for testing:

```
BEGIN;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "data"."item" CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "data"."item" (
    "id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "marked_for_deletion" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "name_" citext NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,

CONSTRAINT item_id_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE INDEX item_marked_for_deletion_ix_bgin ON "data"."item" USING GIN("marked_for_deletion") WHERE marked_for_deletion = true;

ALTER TABLE "data"."item" OWNER TO "user_change_structure";
COMMIT;
```

I've been inserting to this table, and many others, using multi-value inserts, along the lines of:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT 
   bundle up hundres or thousands of rows
  ON CONFLICT do what I need
COMMIT or ROLLBACK on the client side
```

Works fine. But how do you make a multi-value statement safe? That's what I can't figure out. This is one of those areas where I can't reason about the problem well. I don't have the appetite, aptitude, or patience for hacking things. That I can't think up an exploit means nothing, I would *suck* as a hacker. And, for that matter, I'm generally more concerned about errors than evil in code, since I run into errors a whole lot more often.

The standard advice I see for safe insertion is to use a prepared statement. A prepared statement for an INSERT is pretty much a temporary, runtime function for interpolation on a code template. For me, it's simpler to write an actual function, like this one:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS data.item_insert_s (uuid, boolean, citext);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.item_insert_s (uuid, boolean, citext) 
  RETURNS int
AS $$
INSERT INTO item (
    id,
    marked_for_deletion,
    name_)

VALUES
    ($1,$2,$3)

ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET 
    marked_for_deletion = EXCLUDED.marked_for_deletion,
    name_ = EXCLUDED.name_;

SELECT 1; -- No clue what to return, but you have to return something.

$$ LANGUAGE sql;

ALTER FUNCTION data.item_insert_s(uuid, boolean, citext) OWNER TO user_bender;
```

All of that works, and I've tried some timing tests. I truncate the table, do a multi-value insert, truncate, do a series of function call inserts, and see what the difference is. I've tried multiple runs, doing the operations in different orders, etc. Both cases use a BEGIN/COMMIT block in the same way, so I'll end up with the same number of transactions on either test. The results vary more across tests than within them, but the multi-value insert is always faster. Congratulations to me for confirming the obvious.

Is there a way to safely do bulk inserts and updates? It occurred to me that I could write a function that takes an array or arrays, parse it out, and run the code in a loop within the function. I'd like to test that out, but get flummoxed by the Postgres array syntax. I've looked around, and it sounds like an array of objects and a foreach loop might be just what I'm after. I've looked around, and this is a topic that has been addressed, but I haven't found a straightforward example of how to prepare data for insertion, and the the unpacking of it. I'm suspecting that I won't be able to use SQL and a plain unnest() because 1) I want to safe the inputs and 2) I might have functions that don't take all of the fields in a table in their input.

To make things a bit easier, I'm fine with functions with fixed parameter lists, and array inputs with fixed formats. I'll write code generators for my various tables, so I don't need to make the Postgres-side code any more complex than necessary.

Thanks for any help!

Note: I got a message to explain why this question is different than my newer, related question:

[Improving a function that UPSERTs based on an input array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517980/improving-a-function-that-upserts-based-on-an-input-array/57519752#57519752)

Answer: Yes, it's the same starting point. In this question, I was asking about SQL injection, in the second question I was trying to focus on the array-input solution. I'm not quite sure when to split out new questions, and when to let questions turn into multi-part threads.

Comment: It feels like you've gone down a rabbit hole of XY problems and you seem to flip-flop between things. What are you actually trying to do? What are you trying to prove?  And why? You seem to have written some test.. things, but how do those relate to your real-life  use of the DB? You mention "on the client side" which implies there's some sort of app that's being used to query / manipulate the DB?

Comment: I've got two connected goals:

1. Avoid SQL injection defects or attacks. (Safety)
2. Bulk insert rather than insert row-by-row. (Speed)

We've got a lot of individual databases that push data up to Postgres to get them into our analytics pipeline. I'm concerned that malformed values in that data could lead to injection attacks/defects. 

I can write an insert function (or prepared statement) per table, but single-row inserts are _significantly_ slower than batch inserts. So I'm now wondering about an insert function that takes data bundled as an array and does the inserts that way.

Comment: There is `COPY`, intended for bulk copying. (also avialable via pqlib)

Comment: COPY is great. What I'm after in this case is a SQL-injection safe form of UPSERT, which isn't quite what COPY is about. It bails on errors, etc. 

My simplest question is "what is the injection-safe way to do a multi-value insert?"

Thanks

Comment: Copy into a temp table, and do an *upsert* from there. There is no risk of injection.

Comment: I hadn't considered using COPY that way, I'll give it some thought. I'm still interested in the idea of passing an array into a function and processing it server side. I'd be grateful for suggestions along those lines too.

Answer (score 3):

It's morning here on the Far South Coast of NSW, and I figured I'd take another crack at this. I should have mentioned before that our deployment environment is RDS, which makes COPY less appealing. But the idea of passing in an array where each element includes the row data is *very* appealing. It's much like a multi-value INSERT, but with different syntactic sugar. I've poked at arrays in Postgres a bit, and always come away befuddled by the syntax. I found a few really excellent threads with lots of details from some top posters to study:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224785/pass-array-of-mixed-type-into-stored-function

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131505/use-array-of-composite-type-as-function-parameter-and-access-it

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225176/how-to-pass-an-array-to-a-plpgsql-function-with-variadic-parameter/

From there, I've got a working test function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS data.item_insert_array (item[]);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.item_insert_array (data_in item[]) 
  RETURNS int
AS $$
INSERT INTO item (
    id, 
    marked_for_deletion, 
    name_)

SELECT
    d.id, 
    d.marked_for_deletion,
    d.name_

FROM unnest(data_in) d

ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET 
    marked_for_deletion = EXCLUDED.marked_for_deletion,
    name_ = EXCLUDED.name_;

SELECT cardinality(data_in); -- array_length() doesn't work. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

$$ LANGUAGE sql;

ALTER FUNCTION data.item_insert_array(item[]) OWNER TO user_bender;
```

To close the circle, here's an example of some input:

```
select * from item_insert_array(

    array[
        ('2f888809-2777-524b-abb7-13df413440f5',true,'Salad fork'),
        ('f2924dda-8e63-264b-be55-2f366d9c3caa',false,'Melon baller'),
        ('d9ecd18d-34fd-5548-90ea-0183a72de849',true,'Fondue fork')
        ]::item[]
    );
```

Going back to my test results, this performs roughly as well as my original multi-value insert. The other two methods I posted originally are, let's say, 4x slower. (The results are pretty erratic, but they're always a lot slower.) But I'm still left with my original question:

*Is this injection safe?*

If not, I guess I need to rewrite it in PL/pgSQL with a FOREACH loop and EXECUTE...USING or FORMAT to get the injection-cleaning text processing/interpolcation features there. Does anyone know?

I have a lot of other questions about this function (Should it be a procedure so that I can manage the transaction? How do I make the input anyarray? What would be a sensible result to return?) But I think I'll have to pursue those as their own questions.

Thanks for any help!